# Permission denied when attempting to run executable on LVM partition

Tags: lvm

I have partitioned my drive with LVM, creating separate logical volumes (LV) for the root and storage. Whenever I try to execute something located on the storage LV, I receive a `Permission denied` error.

If I move and execute the same thing on the root LV, it works as expected. I have checked the settings of both LVs, and there doesn't appear to be any noticeable difference. I must be overlooking something.

```
$ sudo lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                NxdCBB-MS1U-vu2Y-iyH6-Tqij-OF1P-ZqqBn8
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2023-05-26 16:30:19 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                500.00 GiB
  Current LE             128000
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  <Redacted>

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/Storage
  LV Name                Storage
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                Jy2viP-GC1B-JyQH-mSvf-k337-A30r-f4xqI8
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time OQC-LT-70, 2023-06-19 10:23:51 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.36 TiB
  Current LE             357350
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you're mounting wrong?

Comment: My fstab options are set to `defaults,user` which should mean `exec` is set as part of the defaults.

Comment: I ran `cat /proc/mounts` and it was indeed mounted with `noexec`. Defining it explicitly solved the issue.